# Starting django-socketio in production

Tags: python, django, gevent-socketio

I installed [Django-socketio](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-socketio) because it seems like the best way to implement chat by myself. The problem I have is that when I run 
`python manage.py runserver_socketio host:port` it runs and I can't close the terminal or it will stop working, how can I get around that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with command nohup.

So you start the server with `nohup python manage.py runserver_socketio host:port &` (& to start in backgroud). The result is stored in a nohup.out file...

Comment: Please tell me how to run during devlopment?
python manage.py runserver_socketio host:port
what are the host and port values?
and when we want to run on production, what would be the values then.